# Teb Local Planner : Increasing x linear velocity

Tags: navigation, teb-local-planner, velocity, planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm currently using the teb local planner for a tricycle robot and it gives good results but I would like to i Increasing the max_vel_x parameter doesn't seem to change the speed and I am having a hard time with it with all the optimization parameters. Increasing the maximum x linear velocity doesn't change anything and cmd_vel remains around 0.25/0.3 m/s maximum.

I looked a bit at the the teb questions and it seems for example, that putting weight_acc_lim* to 0.0 or changing the footprint model would reduce computation time . When setting weight_acc_lim* to 0.0, the robot is not able to move anymore and the error " trajectory not feasible" appears on every goal I am trying to send.

Here is my current configuration for teb local planner :

**TebLocalPlannerROS:**

odom_topic: odom
map_frame: /odom

**# Trajectory**

teb_autosize: True

dt_ref: 0.3

dt_hysteresis: 0.1

global_plan_overwrite_orientation: True

allow_init_with_backwards_motion: False

max_global_plan_lookahead_dist: 1.5

feasibility_check_no_poses: 5

**# Robot**

max_vel_x: 0.8

max_vel_x_backwards: 0.2

max_vel_y: 0.0

max_vel_theta: 0.4

acc_lim_x: 0.15

acc_lim_y: 0.0

acc_lim_theta: 0.05

**# Carlike robot parameters**

min_turning_radius: 0.15      # Min turning radius of the carlike robot (compute value using a model or adjust with rqt_reconfigure manually)

wheelbase: 0.864                 # Wheelbase of our robot

cmd_angle_instead_rotvel: True # stage simulator takes the angle instead of the rotvel as input (twist message)

**footprint_model:** # types: "point", "circular", "two_circles", "line", "polygon"

```
type: "polygon"

radius: 0.2 # for type "circular"

line_start: [0.0, 0.0] # for type "line"

line_end: [0.4, 0.0] # for type "line"

front_offset: 0.2 # for type "two_circles"

front_radius: 0.2 # for type "two_circles"

rear_offset: 0.2 # for type "two_circles"

rear_radius: 0.2 # for type "two_circles"

vertices: [[1.1,0.4],[-0.3,0.4],[-0.3,-0.4],[1.1,-0.4]]
```

**# GoalTolerance**

xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2

yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.2

free_goal_vel: False

**# Obstacles**

min_obstacle_dist: 0.5

include_costmap_obstacles: True

costmap_obstacles_behind_robot_dist: 1

obstacle_poses_affected: 30

costmap_converter_plugin: ""

costmap_converter_spin_thread: True

costmap_converter_rate: 5

**# Optimization**

no_inner_iterations: 5

no_outer_iterations: 4

optimization_activate: True

optimization_verbose: False

penalty_epsilon: 0.05

weight_max_vel_x: 590

weight_max_vel_theta: 120

weight_acc_lim_x: 370

weight_acc_lim_theta: 200

weight_kinematics_nh: 10000

weight_kinematics_forward_drive: 1000

weight_kinematics_turning_radius: 300

weight_optimaltime: 860

weight_obstacle: 50

weight_dynamic_obstacle: 10 # not in use yet

**# Homotopy Class Planner**

enable_homotopy_class_planning: True

enable_multithreading: True

simple_exploration: False

max_number_classes: 4

selection_cost_hysteresis: 1.0

selection_obst_cost_scale: 1.0

selection_alternative_time_cost: False

roadmap_graph_no_samples: 15

roadmap_graph_area_width: 5

h_signature_prescaler: 0.5

h_signature_threshold: 0.1

obstacle_keypoint_offset: 0.1

obstacle_heading_threshold: 0.45

visualize_hc_graph: False

I tried lots of combinations with rqt_recofnigure and this one gives good results except that i seems to block the linear velocity to small values. I would like to rpevent the robot from going backwards and avoid obstacles coming on its way. Is there any parameters changes that could help keep this characteristics while increasing the velocity of the robot.

Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273707/teb-local-planner-:-increasing-x-linear-velocity/) by [TeddyBear](https://answers.ros.org/users/26510/teddybear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-10-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
acc_lim_x: 0.15
acc_lim_theta: 0.05
```

I think your acceleration limits, especially the theta acceleration, are too low. I have found that if i set the theta acceleration limit very low, TEB will try to reverse more often than just rotate in place. This makes sense intuitively because the system will have to spend more time rotating then reversing. Also try upping your max_vel_theta limit.

By allowing the robot to rotate more freely you should find that it will stop trying to back up as much. You should also be able to relax the weight_kinematics_forward_drive to allow for reverse movements that are sometimes necessary.

Also, you have a whole bunch of footprint types listed. You should only have two lines, the footprint_model type and its corresponding option. For example if you want to use a polygon, have:

```
footprint:
    type: "polygon"
    vertices: [[1.1,0.4],[-0.3,0.4],[-0.3,-0.4],[1.1,-0.4]]
```

Here is my base_local_planner_params.yaml file for TEB configuration for a 3 wheeled differential robot that works ok:

TebLocalPlannerROS:

```
odom_topic: odom
map_frame: /odom
   
# Trajectory
 
teb_autosize: True
dt_ref: 0.4
dt_hysteresis: 0.1
global_plan_overwrite_orientation: True
# This is so we stick to the global plan and don't make s's 
max_global_plan_lookahead_dist: 2.0
feasibility_check_no_poses: 5
# not sure what this does
global_plan_viapoint_sep: .5
   
# Robot
        
max_vel_x: 0.35
max_vel_x_backwards: 0.2
max_vel_theta: 0.7
acc_lim_x: 0.5
# If this is low, we overshoot on a rotate
acc_lim_theta: 0.5
min_turning_radius: 0.0
footprint_model: 
   type: "polygon"
   vertices: [
       [ 0.45, 0.375],
       [ -0.45, 0.375],
       [ -0.45, -0.375],
       [ 0.45, -0.375],
   ]

# GoalTolerance
   
xy_goal_tolerance: 0.3
yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.2
free_goal_vel: False
   
# Obstacles
   
min_obstacle_dist: 0.01
inflation_dist: 0.2
include_costmap_obstacles: True
costmap_obstacles_behind_robot_dist: 1.0
obstacle_poses_affected: 30
costmap_converter_plugin: ""
costmap_converter_spin_thread: True
costmap_converter_rate: 5

# Optimization
   
no_inner_iterations: 5
no_outer_iterations: 4
optimization_activate: True
optimization_verbose: False
penalty_epsilon: 0.04
weight_max_vel_x: 2
weight_max_vel_theta: 1
weight_acc_lim_x: 1
weight_acc_lim_theta: 1
weight_kinematics_nh: 1000
weight_kinematics_forward_drive: 150
weight_kinematics_turning_radius: 1
weight_optimaltime: 1
weight_obstacle: 50
weight_dynamic_obstacle: 10 
selection_alternative_time_cost: False
weight_viapoint: 100


# Homotopy Class Planner

enable_homotopy_class_planning: True
enable_multithreading: True
simple_exploration: False
max_number_classes: 4
roadmap_graph_no_samples: 15
roadmap_graph_area_width: 5
h_signature_prescaler: 0.5
h_signature_threshold: 0.1
obstacle_keypoint_offset: 0.1
obstacle_heading_threshold: 0.45
visualize_hc_graph: False
```

---

Originally posted by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) with karma: 258 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4